# Movement diagonally is not consistent

Tags: c++, movement, sdl2, keyboard

I am making my own game and this is the first time i'm doing so. so I hope you can forgive stupid mistakes. Im making this in C++ and using the SDL2 framework.

Currently, I have a character on my screen which i am trying to move across the screen.
I am encountering an extremely strange bug where moving southwest is different to moving north east (opposite directions). moving SW seems to work correctly but going NE is wrong. When the character moves NE, it does not go east enough. so if SW movement is 225 degrees from north clockwise (correct), then NE is only moving 25 degrees from north clockwise (incorrect). NE movement should be 45 degrees but it is 25 degrees. What possible reason could there be for this happening?

I also noticed that moving north west is faster than moving south east.
I tried to troubleshoot by timing each direction to see if its any particular direction not working. but to my surprise, if I only press 1 movement key, all directions have consistent timings.
I am at a complete loss and i have no idea what is going on.

```
void updateVel(const Uint8 *state) {
    velY = maxVel * (state[SDL_SCANCODE_S] - state[SDL_SCANCODE_W]);
    velX = maxVel * (state[SDL_SCANCODE_D] - state[SDL_SCANCODE_A]);

    //if going diagonal, slow down to limit diagonal speed.
    if (velX != 0 && velY != 0) {
        velX *= 0.707f;
        velY *= 0.707f;
    }
    std::cout << velX << " " << velY << std::endl;
// velX, velY, and maxVel are all floats. 
}
```

Comment: It might be simpler to reason about if you just add all 4 possible directions onto the velocity (if the corresponding key is pressed), then clamp to 1.0? Then you don't really care if they are pressing, 1, 2, 3, or 4 keys at the same time, they can't "game" the system. Also pressing all 4 they are likely to cancel each other out and the velocity will be 0.0 anyway.

Comment: This part of the code looks ok. Can you show us a small console program that reproduces the issue?

Comment: Obligatory comment about [testing floating point values for ==](https://elliotchance.medium.com/comparing-floating-point-numbers-in-c-c-f7aa483d7ae1).

Comment: Ok. I have narrowed down the culprit to the speed limiting. my code above works as expected when I remove the speed limiter, but when I add that code in, everything seems wonky. @pilkch

Comment: @Vaillancourt I tried using "fabs(velX) > 0.1f" but that seemed to make the issue worse for some reason

Comment: @HolyBlackCat here is a link to a video of the issue
https://photos.app.goo.gl/PLWzTMX51vTWbjms7

Comment: Might want to add a cout inside the if and see which condition makes the code go wrong.

Comment: @Vaillancourt I already have the cout at the end. it shows the correct speed but it doesnt actually move at the correct speed.

Comment: Ok I figured it out. I am very unhappy with myself. Turns out my position variables were integers. and since I had type casting going on, the compiler let it happen. I changed my position to floats and all is good now.